# Showing ValueError while taking dot product of matrix

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, dot-product

I wish to multiply two numpy matrices A and B_transformed:

```
    A = 
     [[-1.910095  ]
      [-1.20056174]
      [-0.77669163]
      [ 0.62406999]
      [ 1.1471159 ]
      [ 2.11616247]]

    B = 
      [[ 0.70710678 -0.70710678]
       [ 0.70710678  0.70710678]]

     B_transformed = B[1,:]
                   = [0.70710678 0.70710678]
```

I tried:

```
product = np.dot(A,B_transformed)
```

However I get ValueError:

```
ValueError: shapes (6,1) and (2,) not aligned:
```

By matrices rule, (6,1) X (1,2) is allowed. Then why am I getting valueError?

### Desired Output

```
product = [[-1.35064113 -1.35064113]
           [-0.84892534 -0.84892534]
           [-0.54920392 -0.54920392]
           [ 0.44128412  0.44128412]
           [ 0.81113343  0.81113343]
           [ 1.49635283  1.49635283]]
```

Comment: What you're trying to do is not a dot product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the shape of `B_transformed` is `(2,)`, based on `numpy` [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), `numpy` cannot find a way to broadcast `B_transformed` in order to perform `matmul` with `A`.

In order to get the desired output, you need

```
np.matmul(A,B_transformed[None,:])
```

`B_transformed[None,:]` will reshape `B_transformed` to `(1,2)`

Answer (score 0):

Your `B_transformed` should be `[[0.70710678, 0.70710678]]` instead of `[0.70710678, 0.70710678]`

Answer (score 0):

YOur array shapes:

```
In [38]: A.shape
Out[38]: (6, 1)
In [39]: B.shape
Out[39]: (2, 2)
In [40]: B[1,:]
Out[40]: array([0.70710678, 0.70710678])
In [41]: _.shape
Out[41]: (2,)
```

A (6,1) and (2,) can multiply, producing a (6,2).  This is element-wise multiplication with broadcasting.  It's in effect an `outer product`.

```
In [42]: A*B[1,:]
Out[42]: 
array([[-1.35064112, -1.35064112],
       [-0.84892535, -0.84892535],
       [-0.54920392, -0.54920392],
       [ 0.44128412,  0.44128412],
       [ 0.81113343,  0.81113343],
       [ 1.49635283,  1.49635283]])
```

It can done as a matrix product, provided the 2nd array is (1,2) shape.  Indexing with a list `[1]` does that for us. Or we can add the dimension with `None`.

```
In [43]: A.dot(B[[1],:])
Out[43]: 
array([[-1.35064112, -1.35064112],
       [-0.84892535, -0.84892535],
       [-0.54920392, -0.54920392],
       [ 0.44128412,  0.44128412],
       [ 0.81113343,  0.81113343],
       [ 1.49635283,  1.49635283]])
```

`dot` does not add that leading dimension; only element-wise broadcasting does that.

In cases like the distinctions in shape (2,), (1,2) and (2,1) can be significant, even they all contain the same 2 numbers.